# SharedPreferences not updating value when returning to Activity, but only keeps initial Activity load value

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

So I am trying to use SharedPreferences to pass a value from the Activity to a Class. The problem is the following:

**On initial loading of the Activity, the value is stored in SharedPreferences but if I exit the Activity and return back, and try to update the value, the SharedPreferences does not seem to update and stays at the value of the initial load of the Activity.**

**Some class function**

```
private void populatePlayerQueue(){
        int category_index;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getContext());
        category_index = sharedPreferences.getInt("selected_category", 0);
    }
```

**Activity onResume**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int tmp = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryIndex"));
    //store the category in the shared preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("selected_category", tmp);
    editor.commit();
}
```

**What I am trying to do:**

I have to send an integer from the activity to a specific class and if I come back to the activity then I need to store the update value and so the class will be able to access the newly updated value again. I only have access to the context and not the activity. This causes errors if I try to create an interface callback to communicate with the activity. So this option is eliminated, hence I am trying anything I can to do that.

Comment: provide more info, what your trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

For some better result **remove** the SharedPreference through its key at the time of exit application.

In your case when you exit your application just clear the SharedPreference like:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.remove("selected_category"); //Just remove it by its specific key
editor.commit();
```

Then it will clearly load and save the new value again when you go back to your application on the same key or you can use new one.